# ANDROID.. PLAY / RESUME in Audio RECORDING

Tags: android, audio, recording, resume

In my application (Audio Recorder), I record voice and play it successfully and now i  need to pause the recording and the resume it,

But I found there is no pause/resume available in mediarecorder class,and i managed to find, that the same operation can be done by concatenating two or more audio files while recording...

And now the problem is i dont find any sample codes for doing it,

Does any One hve tried this and Worked it Out??

Pls help...

Thanks